# World's # 1 painter painted something!

Tags: logical-deduction

Come one, come all! Gather around my amazing masterpiece and see if you can guess what I painted! I borrowed the following items and took the raw essence of all of each item and made the painting.

- May's Rock
- London's Double Decker Bus
- Elvis' Denim Jacket
- The Saltine Warrior's team
- Lavender from Martha's Stewart's Garden
- B.B. King's Soul
- Gru's Minions

What do you guys think? ...Hey! Why are you guys leaving? Are you not impressed with my creation?

Question: What did I paint?

Edit: This is my first puzzle so if it is not clear or something is confusing let me know!

Edit 2: Typo from Demin to Denim and Stwart to Stewart for clarity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You painted

> A rainbow

Because

May's Rock:

> May's birthstone is emerald, which is green

London's Double Decker bus:

> These famous buses are red

The Saltine Warrior's team:

> Their mascot is Big Chief Bill Orange

Lavender from Martha Stewart's garden:

> Lavenders are purple

B.B. King's Soul:

> B.B. King is a blues musician

Elvis's denim jacket:

> Is also blue, but maybe could be considered indigo

Gru's Minions:

> Are yellow

Conclusion:

> Together you have all the colours of the rainbow

Comment: Perhaps the "World's #1 painter" is supposed to be God.